# AS3: Smooth touch swipe scroll for iOS

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, scroll, touch

I've been trying to figure out for days now how to get the smooth scrolling on a touch device as all other apps have.. For the time being I've implemented this:

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;

stage.addEventListener (TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, fl_SwipeHandler);

function fl_SwipeHandler(event:TransformGestureEvent):void
{
    switch(event.offsetX)
    {
        // swiped right
        case 1:
        {
            // Start your custom code
            // This example code moves the selected object 20 pixels to the right.

            // End your custom code
            break;
        }
        // swiped left
        case -1:
        {
            // Start your custom code
            // This example code moves the selected object 20 pixels to the left.

            // End your custom code
            break;
        }
    }

    switch(event.offsetY)
    {
        // swiped down
        case 1:
        {
            // Start your custom code
            // This example code moves the selected object 20 pixels down.
            if (PActive == true) {
                dgPlace.verticalScrollPosition = dgPlace.verticalScrollPosition - 60;
            }
            if (SActive == true) {
                dgSubject.verticalScrollPosition = dgSubject.verticalScrollPosition - 60;
            }
            if (OActive == true) {
                dgObject.verticalScrollPosition = dgObject.verticalScrollPosition - 60;
            }
            if (FActive == true) {
                dgFeeling.verticalScrollPosition = dgFeeling.verticalScrollPosition - 60;
            }
            if (AActive == true) {
                dgAction.verticalScrollPosition = dgAction.verticalScrollPosition - 60;
            }
            if (NActive == true) {
                dg.verticalScrollPosition = dg.verticalScrollPosition - 60;
            }
            // End your custom code
            break;
        }
        // swiped up
        case -1:
        {
            // Start your custom code
            // This example code moves the selected object 20 pixels up.
            if (PActive == true) {
                dgPlace.verticalScrollPosition = dgPlace.verticalScrollPosition + 60;
            }
            if (SActive == true) {
                dgSubject.verticalScrollPosition = dgSubject.verticalScrollPosition + 60;
            }
            if (OActive == true) {
                dgObject.verticalScrollPosition = dgObject.verticalScrollPosition + 60;
            }
            if (FActive == true) {
                dgFeeling.verticalScrollPosition = dgFeeling.verticalScrollPosition + 60;
            }
            if (AActive == true) {
                dgAction.verticalScrollPosition = dgAction.verticalScrollPosition + 60;
            }
            if (NActive == true) {
                dg.verticalScrollPosition = dg.verticalScrollPosition + 60;
            }
            // End your custom code
            break;
        }
    }
```

Which basically just says that if a swipe occurs then scroll the active datagrid up or down by 60 units which is 2 rows. Please if anyone has any idea how to do this, I would greatly appreciate the help. ^_^

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. First off, swiping is not scrolling! Why do do you want to implement your own scrolling implementation for a datagrid? The grid comes with it's own scroll container. If you want to use some sort of swiping for your grid (for  whatever reason) I'd strongly recommend using the Gestouch library.

Comment: Swipe scrolling does not work natively within the datagrid on an Air iOS application.. Thanks for the suggestion, i'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion (although I have not yet tried this myself), the swipe experience really depends on the size of the movie clip (or content).

So, maybe instead of using a fixed number 60, you can use something like `dgSubject.height / 3`. ( 3 so that you will get to the end by 3 swipes ).

Just want to throw something to trigger more thinking.

Also, I have just found the following links:
http://www.greensock.com/throwprops/
http://www.swfgeek.net/2011/09/08/greensocks-throwpropsplugin-ipad-test/

See if they solve your issues